# How to force webview to fix scrolling height based on content

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, wkwebview

I'm getting back a height value that is way bigger than the actual size of my content, in `WKWebView`, I calculate the height using this code:

```
 webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight") { (contentHeight, error) in
            guard let contentHeight = contentHeight as? CGFloat, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            print(contentHeight)
            print(webView.bounds.height)
        }
    }
```

in  `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)`
but it gives two different values.

My question is how to force the content to be fixed on the screen, to avoid unwanted scrolling.